# Today, github suddenly block me from accessing my repo with my Personal Access Token

Tags: github, access-denied, personal-access-token

Today, Oct 24 2022, at 15:00, I pushed my repo from the dev machine and then pull it on the production one without troubles.

I used my github name and my personal access token: I made a lot of daily commits against several `private` repo, with no problem until now..

At 17:00, github suddenly stop accessing my push telling me:

```
Username for 'https://github.com': pdipietro
Password for 'https://pdipietro@github.com': 
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/pdipietro/xxxxxxxx.git/'
```

I was able to push using `VSC`, but I'm absolutely unable to pull the repo on the production machine.

I can access [www.github.com](http://www.github.com) using my username and password.

I created a new Personal Access Token `with all permissions` but nothing changed: access is still denied.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What scopes does your new personal access token have?  Are you trying to push any GitHub Actions workflows?

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem was solved after rebooting all the machines: my dev machines and all the machines hosted on Amazon eheI use Github.

The old personal access token is working again.

I cannot explain but should be interesting to have some ideas on `why` the problem happened and `what the problem exactly is`.